# Export high resolution map image in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, export, layouts

I'm trying to save big ortophoto image (34k x 28k px) with overlayed vector contour layer with difference blending mode in order to see contours on every terrain clearly. See an example below:

[image]

When I try to save whole image matching original 1 m resolution using Export map to image or Map composer QGIS always crashes.
I achieved this by exporting 12 atlas tiles and merging again later.
Is there some more straightforward way of doing it?

Comment: Best guess is the image size is causing it to use too much RAM memory. I used to create 500 MB images and laugh when they tired to print them to a printer that only had 128MB ram. Might want to try smaller image and gradually increase size util you find the largest file size you can create. Also consider you can easily create an image you can't print.

Comment: Finally I exported atlas using tiles 10k x 10k px, so there were 12 tiles. Then merged them and clipped using original extent using VRT and gdal_translate.